# Which classifier should I use for game automation?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I suppose I have to pick one from this list:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html

As I need incremental learning.

I'm trying to get machine learning to learn how to play a simple NES game. I'm going to teach the machine some basic data from the game such as player x & y, enemy x & y, points etc.

Based on the data mentioned above the machine should predict which button to press.

So what classifier do you recommend for such project?

Comment: First of all I would not recommend treating playing games as a supervised learning problem. This is as pure example of reinforcement learning as it gets.

Answer (score 1):

Here, let me do a browser search for you:

machine learning train computer to play video game

[first hit](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2015-02-25/google-s-computers-learn-to-play-video-games-by-themselves)

To summarize, this is not a problem you will solve well by choosing a classifier off a menu.  Now, this article is extreme learning: the model trains from the screen image alone (an array of pixels).  If you extract game abstractions (identify objects on the screen), you will have a quicker training period.  However, the matter remains that to play a visual game *well*, you will likely need the learning strategy outlined in the papers from this research: time-based input with delayed reward recognition.

This means that your machine learning gets its feedback from points, lives, or playing time awarded somewhat after a particular *good* action.  For instance, in **Pong**, you might make a 2-shot combination: one to pull your opponent's paddle out of position, the second to slap the ball past him in the opposite corner.  Only after the opponent fails the second defence, do you get the point.

This is not a trivial problem to do well.

Comment: Surely its possible to recommend a classifier?

Comment: Not with the lack of problem definition.  Most of the information you'd need to focus your question, or to develop the answer on your own, is in the search I gave you.  The difficult solution is outlined in the article I linked.

Comment: @unska Prune's right about the short answer being "this is harder than you think it is".  But I recently stumbled on a [Torch project](https://github.com/soumith/cvpr2015/blob/master/DQN%20Training%20iTorch.ipynb) that uses the Google Deep Mind code to learn Pong.   You might be able to find some useful ideas by reading their code.

Comment: Right; that's why I called out **Pong** in particular, as well as the paper on the higher-profile **BrickOut** solution.